# CloneZilla, what are all these files?

Tags: gparted, clonezilla, fdisk, parted

I am trying to restore a clone of a disk, made with CloneZilla some time ago. I'm having trouble in general, and I can't seem to find the help I'm looking for, so I have to learn some of the basics, and hopefully I will be able to help myself.

The first thing that annoys me, is that I can't figure out what the different files mean.

**Image was created with this command:**

The disk image was created with the graphical version of CloneZilla, but in the logfile `clonezilla-img`, it says that it can be done over with the command:

```
ocs-sr -q2 -c -j2 -z1p -i 2000 -p true savedisk 2013-11-05-21-img sda
```

**List of files:**

The image is a folder, with the following files in it.

```
total 25G
1.1K    blkdev.list
 13K    clonezilla-img
   4    disk
9.5K    Info-dmi.txt
 19K    Info-lshw.txt
2.5K    Info-lspci.txt
 169    Info-packages.txt
  80    Info-saved-by-cmd.txt
  30    parts
 26M    sda1.vfat-ptcl-img.gz.aa
303M    sda2.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.aa
 92M    sda3.dd-img.aa
2.0G    sda4.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.aa
2.0G    sda4.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.ab
2.0G    sda4.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.ac
2.0G    sda4.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.ad
2.0G    sda4.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.ae
2.0G    sda4.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.af
1.7G    sda4.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.ag
1.3M    sda5.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.aa
2.0G    sda6.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.aa
2.0G    sda6.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.ab
2.0G    sda6.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.ac
2.0G    sda6.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.ad
2.0G    sda6.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.ae
1.2G    sda6.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.af
  37    sda-chs.sf
 17K    sda-gpt-1st
 16K    sda-gpt-2nd
 18K    sda-gpt.gdisk
 868    sda-gpt.sgdisk
 512    sda-mbr
 799    sda-pt.parted
 710    sda-pt.parted.compact
 250    sda-pt.sf
```

**For example, I would like to know:**

So, for example `sda-gpt-1st`, `sda-gpt-2nd`, `sda-gpt.gdisk` and `sda-gpt.sgdisk`, I guess they are created with a 3rd party tool, perhaps cfdisk, parted, etc. But which? And what are these files for?

Comment: Related to my original problem: http://superuser.com/questions/833320/how-to-restore-partition-table-when-restoring-entire-disk-using-clonezilla

Comment: .sgdisk is probably a printout from the tool `sgdisk`